# rollmin in R similar to zoo package rollmax

Tags: r, zoo

Is there a function for rollmin in the same way rollmean and rollmax work from the zoo package?  I've looked into the zoo help document but can't find anything.

Answer (score 5):

Run `rollmax` on the negative of the values and then negate the result.  For example,

```
library(zoo)

 x <- 1:10

-rollmaxr(-x, 3, fill = NA)
## [1] NA NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

Another possibility is to use `rollapply` with the `min` function:

```
rollapplyr(x, 3, min, fill = NA)
## [1] NA NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `roll_min` from `library(RcppRoll)` the usage is

> roll_min(x, n = 1L, weights = NULL, by = 1L, fill = numeric(0),
>   partial = FALSE, align = c("center", "left", "right"), normalize =
>   TRUE,   na.rm = FALSE)

e.g.

```
roll_min(1:10, 3, fill = NA, align = "right")
#[1] NA NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```