# rollmean fill NAs with original value

Tags: r

I followed this example to do a rolling mean [rollmin in R similar to zoo package rollmax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079861/rollmin-in-r-similar-to-zoo-package-rollmax)

But the first few are filled with NA's. How can I fill the NA's with the original value so that I don't lose datapoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `coalesce` with the original vector to replace the `NA` with that corresponding non-NA element from original vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
coalesce(rollmeanr(x, 3, fill = NA), x)
```

---

If it is a data.frame

```
ctd %>%
    group_by(station) %>%
    mutate(roll_mean_beam = coalesce(rollmeanr(beam_coef, 
         k = 5, fill = NA), beam_coef))
```

#### data

```
x <- 1:10
```

Comment: I have mine slightly different and coalesce doesn't seem to work. I have it as mutate. im not sure - what is the difference? ctd = ctd %>% group_by(station) %>% 
    mutate(roll_mean_beam = roll_median_beam(beam_coef, k = 5, fill = NA)).           when I change mutate to coalesce, it says it can't find beam_coef

Comment: @L55  what is `roll_median_beam` is it a column?

Comment: @L55 if it is a function, can you show the package used.  I updated with the code that could potentially work

Comment: We don't know your `ctd` or beam_coef` Please consider providing small reproducible example

Comment: station and beam_coef are columns. I created a new column called roll_median_beam. im trying to get a 5 point rolling median of beam_coef for each station. that leaves me with NAs at the start for each roll_median_beam which I want to fill with the beam_coef value

Comment: @L55 in your code, you are using `roll_median_beam` as a function (`roll_median_beam(` note the `(`) it is a column

Comment: The code would be `ctd %>%
    group_by(station) %>%
    mutate(roll_mean_beam = coalesce(rollmeanr(beam_coef, 
         k = 5, fill = NA), beam_coef))`

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Using the original values seems a bit bizarre.  Taking the rolling minimum of 1:10 using a width of 3 would give

```
1 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

I think what you really want is to apply `min` to however many points are available so that in this example we get

```
1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Now `rollapplyr` with `partial=TRUE` will use whatever number of points are available if fewer than `width=3` exist at that point.  At the first point only one point is available so it returns `min(x[1])`.  At the second only two points are available so it returns `min(x[1:2])`.  For all the rest it can use three points.  Only zoo is used.

```
library(zoo)

x <- 1:10
rollapplyr(x, 3, min, partial = TRUE)
## [1] 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

**2)** The above seems more logical than filling the first two points with the first two input values but if you really wanted to do that anyways then simply prefix the series with the original values using `c` or use one of the other alternatives shown below.  Only zoo is used.

```
c(x[1:2], rollapplyr(x, 3, min))
## [1] 1 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

pmin(rollapplyr(x, 3, min, fill = max(x)), x)
## [1] 1 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

replace(rollapplyr(x, 3, min, fill = NA), 1:2, x[1:2])
## [1] 1 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

Min <- function(x) if (length(x) < 3) tail(x, 1) else min(x)
rollapplyr(x, 3, Min, partial = TRUE)
## [1] 1 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```